# How to draw a sprite without black transparency key?

Tags: directx9

I would like some help with the following. At the moment when I draw the sprite I want it to be *full* black with no transparency, i.e. 255 alpha channel. But what I get is *half* transparency. How can I fix this ?

Here is my code:

```
bool Black_ImageToTexture(int texWidth, int texHeight, LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 pTexture, 
    int xPos, int yPos)
{
    D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
    // Lock the texture
    HRESULT hResult = pTexture->LockRect(0, &lockedRect, NULL, 0);

    if (FAILED(hResult)) {
        // Failed to lock the texture for whatever reason, cannot continue
        return true;
    }

    // Cast the image data to a BYTE pointer so we can easily step over the pitch
    BYTE *pBits = (BYTE*) lockedRect.pBits;

    // For each row:
    for (UINT y = 0; y < texHeight; ++y) {
        // Get a pointer to the start of this row of texels, 
        // and then advance to next row
        DWORD *pPixel = (DWORD*)pBits;
        pBits += lockedRect.Pitch;

        // Process this row (Swap R and B channels)
        for (UINT x = 0; x < texWidth; ++x) {
            (*pPixel) = 0xFF000000;
            pPixel++; // Next pixel
        }
    }

    pTexture - > UnlockRect(0);
    return true;
}
```

Finally, render it:

```
d3dspt->Draw(test_texture, NULL, &center, NULL, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 255, 255));

if(FAILED( D3DXCreateTexture(g_pd3dDevice_0, 1680, 1050,
    D3DX_SKIP_DDS_MIP_LEVELS(32,D3DX_DEFAULT), D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC, D3DFMT_UNKNOWN,
    D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &test_texture))) 
{ 
    handle_error_code(123238); 
    return E_FAIL; 
} 
else  { 
    Black_ImageToTexture(1680, 1050, test_texture, 0, 0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`D3DX_SKIP_DDS_MIP_LEVELS(32, D3DX_DEFAULT)`, `32` should have been `1` instead .

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if it fixed your problem. To do so, click on the gray checkmark below the up and down arrows.